# Freely move and rotate tip of bendy bone?

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

I have an object that i'd like to be able to translate and rotate freely, while the  bendy bone below stays attached and curves and stretches accordingly. This works in edit mode but not when i switch to pose mode, it only rotates. 
see gif:
[image]

how do i rig this up?
it has to be a single bendy bone because of the weight painting

Comment: Did you perhaps [lock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TaJZ.png) it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's normal behaviour for bones. the bendy bone would have to stretch too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: https://youtu.be/BsJ3Grq_3GM
stretch to constraint and also start and end handle in bendy bones menu